# Скачивание файлов в WebViewer

Tags: webkit, android-sdk, android, webview

У меня есть `webviewer` и он открывает мобильный сайт, но при нажатии на скачку, файл не скачивается. Облазил все, ничего не помогает, вот код из `MainActivity.java`

```
package ru.driveduckpro.*****;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView mWebView;

    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,String contentDisposition, String mimetype,long contentLength) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(intent);
}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://*****/"); 
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

    }

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Операции для выбранного пункта меню
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://***");
            return true;
        case R.id.action_mmy1:
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://***");
            return true;
        case R.id.action_mload1:
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://**");
            return true;
        case R.id.action_mforum1:
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://***");
            return true;
        case R.id.action_mexit1:
            quit();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

}

private void quit() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

};

Comment: Есть такой код, но не могу понять куда его пихать.


mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
          startActivity(i);
        }
    });

Comment: В onCreate()

Comment: можно как бы и отметить правильных ответ, раз "Спасибо, все заработало!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо установить на Ваш **WebView** [**DownloadListener**](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setDownloadListener%28android.webkit.DownloadListener%29). Т.е. так:

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,String contentDisposition, String mimetype,long contentLength)
    {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
       startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, данный код я уже видел, пробовал ставить но у меня пишутся ошибки в первой и последней строчки. Начал учить всего часов 20 назад, могли бы вы показать куда мне этот код пихать?

Comment: Вот такая ошибка в первой строчке
Multiple markers at this line

 - Syntax error on token "setDownloadListener", = expected after 

  this token

 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Comment: весь код из ответа, включая точку с запятой вставьте новой строкой в onCreate и строку:    
     mWebView.loadUrl("http://*****/");     
поставьте последней

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало!